# List comprehension doing duplicate work

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a running python script that reads in a file of phone numbers.  Some of these phone numbers are invalid.

```
import re

def IsValidNumber(number, pattern):
    isMatch = re.search(pattern, number)
    if isMatch is not None:
        return number

numbers = [line.strip() for line in open('..\\phoneNumbers.txt', 'r')]
```

Then I use another list comprehension to filter out the bad numbers:

```
phonePattern = '^\d{10}$'
validPhoneNumbers = [IsValidNumber(x, phonePattern) for x in phoneNumbers 
    if IsValidNumber(x, phonePattern) is not None]
for x in validPhoneNumbers:
    print x
```

Due to formatting, the second list comprehension spans two lines.

The problem is that although the IsValidNumber should only return the number if the match is valid, it also returns 'None' on invalid matches.  So I had to modify the second list comprehension to include:

```
if IsValidNumber(x, phonePattern) is not None
```

While this works, the problem is that for each iteration in the list, the function is executed twice.  Is there a cleaner approach to doing this?

Comment: To make your `isValidNumber` procedure a bit more consistent, you could change the output to True/False depending on whether the number is valid or not.  Since the procedure doesn't modify the number itself, there's little reason to actually return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `isValidFunction` should return True/False (as its name suggests). That way your list comprehension becomes:

```
valid = [num for num in phoneNumbers if isValidNumber(num, pattern)]
```

While you're at it, modify `numbers` to be a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (since you're interested in efficiency):

```
numbers = (line.strip() for line in open("..\\phoneNumbers.txt"))
```

Comment: I think in this instance I might avoid a generator expression, just the way it's used.  The generator will keep the file open (and locked) until it's been exhausted.  I prefer to keep file accesses as quick as possible to avoid potential corruption.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
validPhoneNumbers = [x for x in phoneNumbers if isValidNumber(x, phonepattern)]
```

Since `isValidNumber` returns the same number that's passed in, without modification, you don't actually need that number.  You just need to know that a number is returned at all (meaning the number is valid).

You may be able to combine the whole thing as well, with:

```
validPhoneNumbers = [x.strip() for x in open('..\\phonenumbers.txt', 'r') if isValidNumber(x.strip(), phonePattern)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would change your validity check method to simply return whether the number matches or not, but not return the number itself.

```
def is_valid_number(number):
    return re.search(r'^\d{10}$', number)
```

Then you can filter out the invalid numbers in the first list comprehension:

```
numbers = [line.strip() for line in open('..\\phoneNumbers.txt', 'r')
    if is_valid_number(line.strip())]
```

Comment: I like a more generic phone number validator where you pass in a pattern.  That way, you can use whatever pattern you want depending on the format of the number you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to work with here, including `filter(None, map(isValidNumber, lines))`. Most efficient is probably to let the regular expression do all the work:

```
import re
numpat = re.compile(r'^\s*(\d{10})\s*$', re.MULTILINE)
filecontents = open('phonenumbers.txt', 'r').read()
validPhoneNumbers = numpat.findall(filecontents)
```

This way there is no need for a Python loop, and you get precisely the validated numbers.